# Indent after end of string and before next string in the same line

Tags: notepad++

I have four thousands of records that I need to sort out and I need help indenting. For example, my data is like this:

```
ABC12345   2981101
CBA5-43-21 9019292
```

End result:

```
ABC12345           2981101
CBA5-43-21         9019292
```

How can I accomplish to have at least 7 tab spaces to spread out the record?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to insert spaces or tabs (please, clarify) between column 1 and column 2? If not, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56583393/edit) and add real test cases.

Comment: Which ever one is easier. Instead of a space in between two strings on the same line, I want to add 10 spaces instead of 7. I can increase this number if needed. Some string are longer so I really want to line up the second string for all lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+`
- Replace with: `\t\t`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Replacement:**

```
\t\t    # 2 tabulations, adjust the length as you need
```

**SCreen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am getting closer. Now the only thing is that the second strings are not aligned with the rest of the second strings per row. Because some 1st strings are longer. Any way to aligned them properly? Thank you again!

Comment: Actually, this is great! I pasted it to Excel and it is already adding them to the two columns and aligned automatically. Thank you!

Comment: @DudebePSing: if the lengths are very different, it is not easily possible with Notepad++ and regex. You could try with column mode editing. Menu " Edit > Column mode ... "